# Compiling these simple functions with Numba fails with cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.core.ir.UndefinedType'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I am certainly missing something when it comes to type inference in Numba. I wrote this small sample and can't seem to find out why it is failing to infer the type when compiling. You can repro just by trying to run it:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange


@njit(["void(uint8[::1], int16)"])
def run_a(arr, numeric):
    final_result = run_b(arr, numeric)   # <<== FAILS HERE
    print(final_result)


@njit(["float64(uint8[::1], int16)"], fastmath=True, nogil=True)
def run_b(arr, numeric):
    value1 = 1.0
    value_array = np.zeros(numeric, np.float64)

    return value1 + value_array.sum()


array = np.arange(10, dtype=np.uint8)
run_a(array, 2)
```

It fails with:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'run_b': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.core.ir.UndefinedType'>

File "tests.py", line 7:
def run_a(arr, numeric):
    final_result = run_b(arr, numeric)
    ^
```

Why is it that it can't infer the types in that call? I even annotated the function signatures so there should be no doubt as what type they are, as far as I can tell.

BTW I know this may not get huge gains with Numba. This is just a sample code, I'm trying to understand what's wrong.

What I am missing? How to get this to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue... one must hoist the functions, or else they wont compile. So reversing the order so that run_b comes befre run_a solves fhe issue.